# replace values in second column of a file based on matching values of first column

Tags: linux, awk

I have a fileA.txt which looks like this:

```
title              trial_exp  values
Version            1.0
Blank1                        0.010
Blank2                        0.200
Blank3                        0.100
Test_field_Asia               1.500
Test_field_Europe             0.900
Test_field_America            2.000
```

I have then a fileB.txt which looks like:

```
Test_field_Asia     Thailand
Test_field_Europe   UK
Test_field_America  Mexico
```

I want to match all the names in column 1 in fileA with the names in column 1 of fileB and replace the values in column 2 when a match is found:

Desired output:

```
title               trial_exp   values
Version             1.0
Blank1                          0.010
Blank2                          0.200
Blank3                          0.100
Test_field_Asia     Thailand    1.500
Test_field_Europe   UK          0.900
Test_field_America  Mexico      2.000
```

I tried the following code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{rec[$1]=$2;next}{temp=$1} temp in rec{$2=rec[temp]}1' fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

However, the replacement is not done and I get the original fileA.txt printed ou

Can anybody explain to me what is wrong in this code or suggest alternative solution, please?

Comment: (1) Are you sure you didn't run `$ awk ...`? (2) What is your field separator? It doesn't look like it's tab (e.g. `Blank1<tab><tab>0.010`) or a space character. How do you determine that the second field is empty and the values belong to the third field in `fileA`?

Comment: Please [edit] your sample input and expected output accordingly so that the question contains data we can work with.

Comment: awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next}$3 in A{$3=A[$3]}1' file2 file1

Comment: apparently that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **solution**.

1. Create the file `myscript.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t"}
    FNR==NR{myfile2[$1]=$2; next}
    FNR>1{if(myfile2[$1]){print $1, myfile2[$1], $3,NR}else{print $1,$2,$3}}
' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

2. Execute it:

```bsh
chmod +x myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
```

You'll get this output:

```bsh
Version 1.0 
Blank1      0.010
Blank2      0.200
Blank3      0.100
Test_field_Asia Thailand    1.500   9
Test_field_Europe   UK  0.900   10
Test_field_America  Mexico  2.000   11
```

3. If you want the comma as separator in your output you can change: `OFS=","`
   you'll get this output:

```
Version,1.0,
Blank1,,0.010
Blank2,,0.200
Blank3,,0.100
Test_field_Asia,Thailand,1.500,9
Test_field_Europe,UK,0.900,10
Test_field_America,Mexico,2.000,11
```

4. **Optional.** If you want to include the `fileA.txt` header (first line) *a)* you can simply change the conditional: `FNR>=1` or *b)* rewrite the script in a short way:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t"}
    FNR==NR{myfile2[$1]=$2; next}
    myfile2[$1]{print $1, myfile2[$1], $3; next;}{print $1,$2,$3}
' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

Finally if you want a detailed example, read:
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-multiple-input-files

Comment: hi, I tried your code but I get the original fileA without sub in the 2nd column

Comment: hi sorry, I think it worked, just add to add the same field separator "," in the fileB same as fileA because it did nit have it

Comment: please, can you explain to me the second part of the code after next?

Comment: I understand that in the first part till next, it gets the lines of the fileB and save it into an array, I can run awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","} FNR==NR{myfile2[$1]=$1; print $1}' fileB.tx t to check but after that what does it mean? can you add explanation please?

Comment: FNR>1{if(myfile2[$1]){print $1, myfile2[$1], $3,NR}....this part, the rest I understand that with the else if it does not find match it prints the original lines of fileA

Comment: All lines of first file (```fileB.txt```) are read because the ```next``` instruction. 
```FNR>1``` is used to omit the header of the second file (```fileA.txt```). If you want to print the header line too, just omit it this condition.
**About FNR and NR**: FNR, Number of Records relative to the *current input file*. NR(Number of Records Variable), NR gives you the *total number of records being processed* (in your example the total records of the two files). So, when this script are reading the ```fileB.txt``` FNR and NR are equal. When script are reading the second file, FNR restart to 1.

Comment: You can read this too:
<https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/>

<https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-multiple-input-files>

Answer (score 1):

What you want is essentially a database join. There is a command for that, aptly named `join`. The problem is that it requires sorted input. If the line order is not relevant, you can do this:

```
join -a1 <(sort fileA.txt) <(sort fileB.txt)
```

The -a1 option prints lines that can't be joined. The two <(...) constructs generate temporary files that contain the output of the sort commands. Using your example, the result is

```
Blank1 0.010
Blank2 0.200
Blank3 0.100
Test_field_America 2.000 Mexico
Test_field_Asia 1.500 Thailand
Test_field_Europe 0.900 UK
title trial_exp values
Version 1.0
```

(I just realize that by copying your example, I replaced tabs with spaces)

The *title* and *Version* lines are probably meant to be headers, so that some post-processing would be required.

Comment: hi,thanks, I was also thinking about that, but for me maintaining the order of the lines is necessary